# Update MySQL Table with PHP by Sending Email to Specific Address

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update

I would like to update an entry in MySQL whenever john@example.com gets an email, and only when the email contains certain text.

For example, when john@example.com receives an email with subject `Contact Confirmation`, I would like to search the email for the string `DEALERID` and record the 6 characters that follow (in this case `ABC123`) to an entry in my MySQL table.

I know that usually this can be done with php-IMAP, but since I'm on a shared server, this is not an option.

Is there another way to do what I'm trying to accomplish?

Comment: can you create accounts on the server? a .forward can use a pipe redirect to invoke a php script anytime a mail comes into that account.

Comment: It's a shared server with a hosting company - so probably not..?

Answer (score -1):

1. Write a script that uses [PHP's IMAP library](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.imap.php) to check the user's mailbox.
2. Get your host to configure a cron job to call the script.
3. ???
4. Profit.

Comment: You didn't read my question - PHP IMAP is not an option because the client is on a shared hosting account where I cannot manage the server.

Comment: @AdamD Your host has IMAP functions disabled? And you still pay them money?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but doesn't GoDaddy have PHP-IMAP disabled?

Comment: @AdamD they do. It is on the laundry list of reasons of why hosting with GoDaddy is a terrible idea. It's like renting a car, but you don't get headlights unless you pay for the "Premium Package", aka VPS.